# Seer Medal after 2014

Tags: ingress

What is the current state of the Seer Medal? I thought it got "temporarily suspended" in that way that:

- The locked medal does not appear on the scanner any longer
- Portals submitted until December 2014 do still count
- Portals submitted since January 2015 do NOT count

[Here](https://www.facebook.com/Ingress/photos/a.463739937007011.96998.463638860350452/800681289979539/?type=1&permPage=1) is an original statement from Niantic:

> [...] we’re working to reduce the time needed to process the thousands of new Portal submissions and edits we receive every day. In order to help us address our growing queue of new Portal submissions, starting Dec 31, 2014 we will temporarily suspend the Seer Medal. You will maintain your current Seer Medal status, but new Portals submitted after Dec 31, 2014 will not be counted towards the Seer Medal. Portals submitted on Dec 31 and earlier will be counted.

I just got a portal approved which I submitted on **March 21, 2015**, which bumped my Seer Medal from 14 to 15! How is this possible?

This is additionally strange for another reason: I have 117 portal submissions between March 21 and the portal which last got approved, somewhen in the beginning of December. Thats's more than 3 months skipped.

I have 3 guesses here:

1. Niantic was lying and only removed the locked Medal from the scanner to remove incentives for players to submit new portals. After all their goal was to reduce the time on portal reviews.
2. You have to unlock the Bronze Seer Medal with portals submitted before 2015. Once unlocked you can increase the counter with any portals submitted and gain higher ranks of the Seer Medal.
3. The counter goes up, but no matter how high it gets it won't upgrade the medal. So now I got 14 from 2014 and 1 from 2015. If I get 35 more from 2015 I will have 50 but won't get Silver. If I get 36 more from 2014 I will have 51 and will get Silver.

Whatever it is, guess it will take some time until we really know, since I can only explain the portal submitted in March being processed by accident - and most everyone has no portals from 2015 yet approved.

Comment: Last notice I had was, that niantic will not count the portal aproved if was submitted passed from 31dec. 2014. But is really strange you get counted it

Comment: I have heard it's your "option 3", the counter goes up but you don't get medal upgrade.

Comment: That would be the perfect mess. Because then I can start counting myself how many portals got approved from which year.

Comment: Just forget seer medal. You probably can't get an upgrade anymore. This medal had its use for Niantic at first, but after they were flooded with stupid portal submissions.

Comment: No more portals have been approved since my question above. I still do have unapproved (or better unprocessed) portals from 2014. Interesting though, I recently got a new photo for an existing portal approved I took 9 months ago.

Answer (score 4):

I did receive a [survey invitation](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/3xf277/niantic_survey/) from Niantic and just recently responded to it. From the looks of it, it seems that Niantic is going to put a new automated portal creation mechanism into the game which will get the portal information from their Fieldtrip application. Because it was a targeted survey I couldn't tell if they will additionally go on taking portal submissions from the players but the latest rumours were that they were going to employ a player voted portal approval system into the game.

My guess on the unanswered portal submissions is that they will eventually be processed by Niantic or put into the voting system.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what in that survey suggested it was related to portal approval? I got that invite too but could not finish it. They kicked me after the 2nd question... :-/

Comment: They were asking questions whether the survey participants would like to see commercial places, brand shops, etc as portals, if they would like to visit those places or spend time at them etc. There were some specific questions on Niantic's latest special brand partnerships, if the participant could name some brands and depending on your answers (I guess so because I only named AXA among them) they wanted our thoughts on those businesses (Am I willing to buy insurance from AXA or other insurance companies, how would I classify their services etc)

Answer (score 0):

Portals submitted in 2015 use their new, assumedly automated system so you might get a response within minutes. 
The old queue you have is clearly not being processed like that and the months will roll on as they used to before 31st Dec 2014.

The old ones could get you the badge and the new ones will not.

Comment: I don't see a difference in portals between those submitted in 2014 and 2015. For both I got the same confirmation mail that the portal was submitted. 2015 portals are not processed immediately or I would have already ~200 processed portals. This single one from March was not the first submitted portal in 2015 either and it appears like a mistake/accident or they picked a random one or an editor liked the photo. What do you mean by automated system? AFAIK there still is the same manual process just that (they claim) accepted portals won't count for the Seer Medal.

Comment: The thing is, this accepted portal from 21st March 2015 increased not only the "Portals Discovered" stat but as well increased the counter right in the medal from 14 to 15. And it would be really strange if the counter in the medal gets above the requirements for the certain levels and the medal is stuck with bronze.

Comment: Can you provide a source for that _new, assumedly automated system_?

Comment: No like anything else Niantic its speculation, but how else can they process portals in 2-3 minutes? (widely observed in UTC+1 time nowadays before 9AM)