# When did Google start counting portal submissions towards Seer?

Tags: ingress

I played in the very beginning of Ingress and successfully submitted tons of portals in my area.  I recently came back to it (Dec 2015) and noticed the Seer medal, but that I only had 1 portal counted towards it.  When I go back to portals I know I submitted, the portal information says "Portal information unavailable".  Did I just simply not get credit for these because they weren't tracking yet or is there some error which can be corrected on the Niantic side?

Comment: Probably related: [Seer Medal after 2014](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226319/seer-medal-after-2014?rq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative source for this, but I am pretty sure that this is because the early portal submission mechanism was via email. So there was no reliable way to tell which player submitted a given portal since they didn't necessarily use an email address tied to their Ingress account (and Ingress may not have tried to use that connection even when it was present).

Comment: Correct. I'd have been a higher-scoring Seer if the many portals I'd submitted via email counted. It may also have been the case that the records of the email addresses associated with these portals was lost.

Comment: Ah, bummer. You'd think it wouldn't be that hard to go back and at least match the emails with active accounts. Oh well, appreciate the answer.

Comment: Just as an update, I did find all the old emails showing my portals were approved.  I asked Niantic if they would accept them as proof but they said they don't do that.